# How to visualize word2vec output?

Tags: python, numpy

X = model[model.wv.vocab]

---

ax0.plot(xpts, ypts, '*', X)

---

I just want to plot this word2vec output using numpy. But couldn't figure out , how to do with xpts,ypts in X array.

The ouput(X):

```
[[-0.03848222 -0.03612062  0.00217602 -0.00959375 -0.00433034 -0.0316275 0.01694106 -0.00831801 -0.00622396  0.04329012]
 [-0.00848787 -0.04294299 -0.0176574  -0.02500241  0.00836717  0.03233737 0.02226903 -0.03964857  0.0381722  -0.0259253 ]
 [-0.03853661  0.00317388  0.00614037  0.04335376 -0.00771708 -0.01196922 0.0120947  -0.02529554  0.00420415  0.021986  ]]
```

Comment: numpy does not have plotting functionality, so your question makes no sense.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `nlp` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr=np.array([[10,11,12],[23,232,22],[2,3,2]])
plt.plot(arr)
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!